# (database?) design: saving email template (MailChimp?)

Tags: mysql, templates, database-design

I want my users to be able to create email templates. That means values (maybe even HTML) have to be stored somewhere (I prefer MySQL, if possible).

The only two solutions I can come up with:
Semi custom templates:
- The application provides the HTML, users can change CSS and I store those CSS values in my database (so a possible key-value solution might be possible)

Full custom templates:
- I have to store the whole HTML code in my database

Both of them don't really seem to be perfect. There will be a massive amount of data really fast, which would slow down my database when there will be a lot of users using this template system.

Do I have other options?

Comment: we could poke fun at any solution. That said, this question is too broad / Opinion based

Answer (score 0):

I see no excuse for key-value for CSS.  You don't need to dissect the CSS, you just need to deliver it intact.

Don't worry about "massive amount of data really fast" until you have details -- numbers, size of data, users/second, etc.

"lot of users" -- InnoDB is rather happy to service lots of users.

Come back with some tentative `CREATE TABLEs` and `SELECTs`.